# Error #1010 in as3 when detecting collision

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

im getting a TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
                            at Defender/checkcollision()
                             at Defender/gameloop()

plz tell me how to solve this one.
ill give u the as3 code

```
public function startDefender() {
        gamelevel = 3; //need some improvements here;
        isfiring = true;
        gunposx = gun.x;
        gunposy = gun.y;
        bullets = new Array();
        vehicles = new Array();
        missiles = new Array();
        health = 100;
        hits = 0;
        desiredhits = 10;
        _healthmeter._healthbar.width *= health / 100;
        gun.startGun();
        if(gamelevel != 1){
            setinterceptor();
            startinterceptortimer();
        }
        setvehicletimer();
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameloop);
    }
public function checkcollision(){   //checks for any collision
        //COLLISION: bullets and vehicles
        if((bullets.length != 0) && (vehicles.length != 0)){
            for(var _b:int = bullets.length - 1; _b >= 0; _b--){
                for(var _v:int = vehicles.length - 1; _v >= 0; _v--){
                    if(bullets[_b].hitTestObject(vehicles[_v])){
                        trace("Sucks");
                        bullets[_b].remove();
                        vehicles[_v].remove();
                        //increase the score and update scoremeter and check for desired hits
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

when the bullets hit the vehicles im getting this error
    TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
    at Defender/checkcollision()
    at Defender/gameloop()

plz help me...

Comment: If you're using Flash Professional, please go to Publish Settings and tick 'Permit Debugging', then run the code again and edit your question with the error code. This new error code will show the line the error is coming from.

Comment: the eroor is coming from the hitTestobject and from the checkcollision(); in the gameloop function...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                if(bullets[_b].hitTestObject(vehicles[_v])){
                    trace("Sucks");
                    bullets[_b].remove();
                    vehicles[_v].remove();
                    return;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation on how this solves the issue